# Why is my dictionary insertion splitting my variables up into two numbers instead of one?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to Python and Stack Overflow so please excuse any errors that I make with regards to syntax, grammar, structure, etc.

I have to make a program that reads a text file and extracts the time that every email was sent. Those times should then be stored in a dictionary where I can also track the most emails sent by time. I'm restricted to using only certain functions as this is for a coursera exercise.

I'm almost done with it but I'm stuck on a very weird error that I can't seem to figure out. When inserting my times into a dictionary it sort of splits the number into two numbers and keeps track of them separately, so instead of getting this output:

```
{'04' : 3, '11' : 6, '10' : 2}
```

I am getting:

```
{'0' : 5, '1' : 14 , '4' : 3}
```

I took the code out of the first for loop and the result, instead of giving me:

```
{'16' : 1}
```

It gave me:

```
{'1' : 1, '6' : 1}
```

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
dic = dict()

for line in handle:
        if line.startswith('From '):
            words = line.split()
            
            time = words[5].split(':')
            
            print(time[0])
            
            for word in time[0]:
                dic[word] = dic.get(word, 0 ) + 1
 

print(dic)
```

Comment: When asking questions for code that relies on data, it is important that a minimal example of the data is included in your question.  Sometimes you might want to create fake data for the question - as long as it faithfully represents the actual data.. The easier you make it for *us* to copy and paste from your question (so that we can execute your code and test our solution) the more likely you'll get responses. - Please read [mre].

Comment: Although you haven't posted input data, it is clear that `time[0]` will be a string rather than a list of strings, so that when you loop over it, you are looping over *characters* in that string.

Comment: When you printed stuff at different places in your code was there an obvious place where things went wrong? unexpected result? If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: @alani oh I see, so specifying one certain index within a list will kind of take the list part of it away? I'm not sure if my reply makes sense but after taking the `time[0]` away I see it didn't split the variables up

Comment: @wwii thank you for the advice. I can see that my second for loop is definitely where my problem lies thanks to strategic printing.

Comment: Have you solved your problem then? If so: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

`time[0]` is a single string rather than a list of strings, and therefore looping through it will result in a loop through the characters. That is why my numbers were being 'split' into two characters.